# Is there a way to handle negative indices without if statements?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, indexing, indices

Python handles negative indices so that they subtract from the length. For example, if we have this list `xs = [1,2,3,4]`, doing `xs[-1]` would give us `4`, the last element, which would be the same as `xs[len(xs)-1]`. Now, an easy way to handle this would be the following:

```py
def handle_index(index: int, length: int) -> int:
  if index < 0:
    return length + index
  return index
```

I tried looking into the source code of CPython and NumPy, but I had a bit of trouble finding where they handled negative indices.

Edit: Python lists and Numpy arrays already handle this. I'm implementing a data structure that uses neither of those, and I would like to know how to efficiently support negative indices.

Comment: Why do you want to add extra logic for something that already does what you want?

Comment: Are you asking for the modulo operation? `-1 % 4` results in 3.

Comment: This is handled in compiled code, so it will be hard to find.  Handling for python base objects (lists, strings etc) will be in different places than numpy's.  And any such handling in source code will of little use to you as an interpreted code writer.

Comment: The actual code is probably very similar to yours. You can't do it with modulus in C because C's modulus returns a negative number in this case.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm implementing a data structure that uses a C array behind the scenes, and it doesn't handle negative indices for me. I didn't know I could use `%` for that in Python. I'm more used to the way it works in C like @Barmar mentioned, e.g. `-1 % 4` => `-1`

Comment: Python code we worry more about `for` statements than `if` ones, at least when it comes to efficiency.  But once we get into `c` code, none of those interpreter level notions of efficiency apply.  You may save yourself some coding work if you can find functions that do the job for you, but that's not a matter of run time efficiency.

Comment: @hpaulj the actual code handling the indices would be in C code, and there would be Python code that calls the C code. For this specific one, I would just send the index as is, and then the C function would handle the conversion. I realize the question is very poorly written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CPython, [`sliceobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/81b9d9ddc20837ecd19f41b764e3f33d8ae805d5/Objects/sliceobject.c#L394-L537) handles converting a slice like `start:stop:stride` into bare indices. Negative `start` and `stop` are handled with code like this:

```c
start = evaluate_slice_index(self->start);
if (start == NULL)
    goto error;

if (_PyLong_Sign(start) < 0) {
    /* start += length */
    PyObject *tmp = PyNumber_Add(start, length);
```

(Note that the correct calculation in your code would be `return length + index` not `length - index`, since `index` is negative.)

The [full code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/81b9d9ddc20837ecd19f41b764e3f33d8ae805d5/Objects/sliceobject.c#L394-L537) has no shortage of `if` statements:

```c
/* Compute slice indices given a slice and length.  Return -1 on failure.  Used
   by slice.indices and rangeobject slicing.  Assumes that `len` is a
   nonnegative instance of PyLong. */

int
_PySlice_GetLongIndices(PySliceObject *self, PyObject *length,
                        PyObject **start_ptr, PyObject **stop_ptr,
                        PyObject **step_ptr)
{
    PyObject *start=NULL, *stop=NULL, *step=NULL;
    PyObject *upper=NULL, *lower=NULL;
    int step_is_negative, cmp_result;

    /* Convert step to an integer; raise for zero step. */
    if (self->step == Py_None) {
        step = _PyLong_GetOne();
        Py_INCREF(step);
        step_is_negative = 0;
    }
    else {
        int step_sign;
        step = evaluate_slice_index(self->step);
        if (step == NULL)
            goto error;
        step_sign = _PyLong_Sign(step);
        if (step_sign == 0) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
                            "slice step cannot be zero");
            goto error;
        }
        step_is_negative = step_sign < 0;
    }

    /* Find lower and upper bounds for start and stop. */
    if (step_is_negative) {
        lower = PyLong_FromLong(-1L);
        if (lower == NULL)
            goto error;

        upper = PyNumber_Add(length, lower);
        if (upper == NULL)
            goto error;
    }
    else {
        lower = _PyLong_GetZero();
        Py_INCREF(lower);
        upper = length;
        Py_INCREF(upper);
    }

    /* Compute start. */
    if (self->start == Py_None) {
        start = step_is_negative ? upper : lower;
        Py_INCREF(start);
    }
    else {
        start = evaluate_slice_index(self->start);
        if (start == NULL)
            goto error;

        if (_PyLong_Sign(start) < 0) {
            /* start += length */
            PyObject *tmp = PyNumber_Add(start, length);
            Py_DECREF(start);
            start = tmp;
            if (start == NULL)
                goto error;

            cmp_result = PyObject_RichCompareBool(start, lower, Py_LT);
            if (cmp_result < 0)
                goto error;
            if (cmp_result) {
                Py_INCREF(lower);
                Py_DECREF(start);
                start = lower;
            }
        }
        else {
            cmp_result = PyObject_RichCompareBool(start, upper, Py_GT);
            if (cmp_result < 0)
                goto error;
            if (cmp_result) {
                Py_INCREF(upper);
                Py_DECREF(start);
                start = upper;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Compute stop. */
    if (self->stop == Py_None) {
        stop = step_is_negative ? lower : upper;
        Py_INCREF(stop);
    }
    else {
        stop = evaluate_slice_index(self->stop);
        if (stop == NULL)
            goto error;

        if (_PyLong_Sign(stop) < 0) {
            /* stop += length */
            PyObject *tmp = PyNumber_Add(stop, length);
            Py_DECREF(stop);
            stop = tmp;
            if (stop == NULL)
                goto error;

            cmp_result = PyObject_RichCompareBool(stop, lower, Py_LT);
            if (cmp_result < 0)
                goto error;
            if (cmp_result) {
                Py_INCREF(lower);
                Py_DECREF(stop);
                stop = lower;
            }
        }
        else {
            cmp_result = PyObject_RichCompareBool(stop, upper, Py_GT);
            if (cmp_result < 0)
                goto error;
            if (cmp_result) {
                Py_INCREF(upper);
                Py_DECREF(stop);
                stop = upper;
            }
        }
    }

    *start_ptr = start;
    *stop_ptr = stop;
    *step_ptr = step;
    Py_DECREF(upper);
    Py_DECREF(lower);
    return 0;

  error:
    *start_ptr = *stop_ptr = *step_ptr = NULL;
    Py_XDECREF(start);
    Py_XDECREF(stop);
    Py_XDECREF(step);
    Py_XDECREF(upper);
    Py_XDECREF(lower);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I just changed the `-` to `+`. Thanks, for that. I'll check the code. Are all indices handled as slices internally?

Comment: I don't know. This is my first foray into CPython's source code. Unsurprisingly, it's a large codebase.